# JColorChooser and JButton - GUI programming

Tags: jbutton, jcolorchooser

i'm writing a simple paint program and i got everything done except that I don't know how to display the color in the same JButton.  Please look at the image below..My program is on the left, and the "Color..." button supposed to have a color square next to it (The program on the right). How does one do it? I've tried to look around but no luck. Any suggestion please let me know. Thank you.

[image]